# Android - Linear/Relative Layout, same line and next line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

So, I'm currently in the process of creating my first Android app. It's been a difficult battle, but I'm somehow hanging in there. Stuck on the design now though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:contentDescription="paintable circle"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/circle" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/datetime"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="60dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:paddingLeft="6dip"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dip"
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This gives a nice list, with the title in the top left, and the date in the far top right. But I want a textview under the title, same font size as the datetime, and another textview under the datetime with the same font size. I've tried adding another LinearLayout, a RelativeLayout, without any extra Layouts, but it just doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RelativeLayout

place the title on the top left

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
```

place the date time on the right with

```
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
```

Then for each of the TextViews you want to place under a component, use

```
android:layout_below = (give the id of the control )
```

Cheers